# Merge two html reports using powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have two html reports. need to combine those 2 report as single one.

```
(Get-Content "C:\TEMP\File1.html") + (Get-Content "C:\TEMP\File2.html") |
    Set-Content "C:\TEMP\Combined.html
```

The above code working fine. While combining there is no gap between 2 html report.

Is there any way to give space between 2 combined reports?

Comment: You need to parse your HTML (tables?) to a collection of objects, merge them and convert them back to html. In other words, please share more details, like your HTML content (in the question), if you looking for a more detailed answer.

Comment: can you get the raw data that was used to create the HTML pages? if so, then you can use that to build your new report.